# Create a column by applying a conditional statement to multiple other columns of dtypes datetime and integer

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks similar to this (except the Visits go up to 74 and there are several hundred clients - I have simplified it here).

```
Client    Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4     Visit_5     Eligible  Active     
Client_1  2016-05-10  2016-05-25  2016-06-10  2016-06-25  2016-07-10  0         0  
Client_2  2017-05-10  2017-05-25  2017-06-10  2017-06-25  2017-07-10  0         0  
Client_3  2018-09-10  2018-09-26  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  1         0  
Client_4  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  2018-11-26  2018-12-10  1         1
```

I want to create a new column called `Visit in Window` with two values, 0 and 1. I want to set `Visit in Window` to equal 1 if the Client is `Eligible` (value of '1' in the `Eligible` column) AND if the Client is `Active` (value of '1' in the `Active` column) AND if **any one** of the 5 columns from `Visit_1` to `Visit_5` contains a date that falls between `2018-10-25` and `2018-12-15`.

So, I want to end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Client    Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4     Visit_5     Eligible  Active  Visit_in_Window    
Client_1  2016-05-10  2016-05-25  2016-06-10  2016-06-25  2016-07-10  0         0       0  
Client_2  2017-05-10  2017-05-25  2017-06-10  2017-06-25  2017-07-10  0         0       0  
Client_3  2018-09-10  2018-09-26  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  1         0       0  
Client_4  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  2018-11-26  2018-12-10  1         1       1
```

I can do this for one column by using the following code

```
df['Visit_in_Window'] = 0
df.loc[((df.Eligible == 1) & (df.Active == 1) &
        (df.Visit_1 > '2018-10-24') & 
        (df.Visit_1 < '2018-12-16')), 'Visit_in_Window'] = 1
```

However, I do not know how to do perform this action on multiple columns at the same time. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is certainly a way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([
    ("Client", ["Client_1", "Client_2", "Client_3", "Client_4"]),
    ("Visit_1", ["2016-05-10", "2017-05-10", "2018-09-10", "2018-10-10"]),
    ("Visit_2", ["2016-05-25", "2017-05-25", "2018-09-26", "2018-10-26"]),
    ("Visit_3", ["2016-06-10", "2017-06-10", "2018-10-10", "2018-11-10"]),
    ("Visit_4", ["2016-06-25", "2017-06-25", "2018-10-26", "2018-11-26"]),
    ("Visit_5", ["2016-07-10", "2017-07-10", "2018-11-10", "2018-12-10"]),
    ("Eligible", [0, 0, 1, 1]),
    ("Active", [0, 0, 0, 1])
]))

df["Visit_in_Window"] = (
    df["Eligible"] & df["Active"] & (
        (("2018-10-25" < df["Visit_1"]) & (df["Visit_1"] < "2018-12-15")) |
        (("2018-10-25" < df["Visit_2"]) & (df["Visit_2"] < "2018-12-15")) |
        (("2018-10-25" < df["Visit_3"]) & (df["Visit_3"] < "2018-12-15")) |
        (("2018-10-25" < df["Visit_4"]) & (df["Visit_4"] < "2018-12-15")) |
        (("2018-10-25" < df["Visit_5"]) & (df["Visit_5"] < "2018-12-15"))
    )
)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Which prints:

```
   Client     Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4     Visit_5  Eligible  Active Visit_in_Window
 Client_1  2016-05-10  2016-05-25  2016-06-10  2016-06-25  2016-07-10         0       0           False
 Client_2  2017-05-10  2017-05-25  2017-06-10  2017-06-25  2017-07-10         0       0           False
 Client_3  2018-09-10  2018-09-26  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10         1       0           False
 Client_4  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  2018-11-26  2018-12-10         1       1            True
```

---

**Update**

For a variable number `N` of columns from `Visit_1` to `Visit_N`, this should work:

```
N = 5
visits = pd.DataFrame([(("2018-10-25" < df["Visit_" + str(i)]) & (df["Visit_" + str(i)] < "2018-12-15")) for i in range(1, N + 1)])
print(visits)
df["Visit_in_Window"] = df["Eligible"] & df["Active"] & visits.any()
```

Which prints:

```
             0      1      2      3
Visit_1  False  False  False  False
Visit_2  False  False  False   True
Visit_3  False  False  False   True
Visit_4  False  False   True   True
Visit_5  False  False   True   True
```

As you can see, only columns 2 and 3 (client 3 and 4) have `True` where they had visits inside the date range. `any` will take care of the "merging" which was done beforehand with bitwise operator `|`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts - this would certainly work, however, my problem is that I'm looking to apply this action to 73 Visit columns - 'Visit_1' to 'Visit_73' (the 5 Visit columns above were just to explain the issue). I could write it out 73 times, but I was wondering if there was a way I could call on all of the relevant columns at once e.g. by writing something like [:, 'Visit_1':'Visit_73']. What do you think?

Comment: How would I do that? What would that look like? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million Jayjayy, that works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I have now checked it

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways to do it is the same as you suggested in the question, but with additional 'or' statements

```
df['Visit_in_Window'] = 0
df.loc[
            (df.Eligible == 1) & 
            (df.Active == 1) & 
            ( ((df.Visit_1 > '2018-10-24') & (df.Visit_1 < '2018-12-16')) |
              ((df.Visit_2 > '2018-10-24') & (df.Visit_2 < '2018-12-16')) |
              ((df.Visit_3 > '2018-10-24') & (df.Visit_3 < '2018-12-16')) |
              ((df.Visit_4 > '2018-10-24') & (df.Visit_4 < '2018-12-16')) |
              ((df.Visit_5 > '2018-10-24') & (df.Visit_5 < '2018-12-16')) 
            ) , 

'Visit_in_Window'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts - this would certainly work, however, my problem is that I'm looking to apply this action to 73 Visit columns - 'Visit_1' to 'Visit_73' (the 5 Visit columns above were just to explain the issue). I could write it out 73 times, but I was wondering if there was a way I could call on all of the relevant columns at once e.g. by writing something like [:, 'Visit_1':'Visit_73']. What do you think?